# React - Rendered item is not updating after initial render. When props change, should select different data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Rendered a state that is not updating when props change.

```js
    componentDidMount(){
        var count = 0;
        var dist = 0;
        (this.props.data).map(item => {
            if(item.type === this.props.selectedType){
                return(
                    dist = dist + item.distance,
                    count++
                    )
                }
            })
            this.setState({
                avg: dist/count
            })
        }
```

I have tried `shouldComponentUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps`

the state of `this.state.avg` has been initialised in constructor but when calling this state in `render` it renders once but doesnt update when prop of 'selectedType' is changed by a different component.

Comment: What have you tried within `componentWillReceiveProps` ? Please post the whole class.

Comment: This is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` is only called once and is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. So it won't have any effect if your props change.

This should work. You can use the `componentDidUpdate` method. It will run after the updating has happened.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevProps.selectedType !== this.props.selectedType) {
     // do something
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` worked better.  The props were updated.

Comment: @QATester19 `componentWillUpdate` is deprecated. It will be deprecated in React 17. It will work now, but according to the docs you should use `componentDidUpdate`. You should avoid using `componentWillUpdate`

Comment: in `componentWillUpdate` i use `this.setState()` however it does not set state correctly when using  `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: It's insanity that devs have to listen to changes to props and THEN trigger an update. It's obvious if the props change it's because we want an update. The way React was engineered creates more work than it solves.

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` calls only once, and doesn't react on any props changing

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM
>   nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint,
>   this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

for reaction on some props changing you have to use `componentDidUpdate`

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.
>   This method is not called for the initial render.

Notes:

`componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. Please don't use it.

Read [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class). It's base thing for development of good website